more than one 10-q?
Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to using python in data extraction.
When I extract data from EDGAR, there is something that troubles me.
When I fetch 10-Q reports, several similar but not identical files appear. I understand that duplicate reports can occur for various reasons.
However, is there a way to automatically identify which one is correct?
Ex. MSFT, GrossProfit, different value in Q3 & Q2
MSFT
Using 'CY' in item['frame'] will lose data
Ex. AAPL, Asset, same value, but no 'CY' in
frame value, lose 2022-09-24
AAPL

Just guessing, but maybe the one with the most recent start and end dates.

This isn't really a programming question, it's about how to understand this data set. Once you decide the criteria, turning that into code is a separate problem (hopefully a very easy one).

yep, I think I got it. thanks for your advice.
